# Drupal module write to database using FAPI

Tags: drupal-6

Does anyone know of a tutorial that shows creating a form and writing that data to a database? This is what I am trying to accomplish or can anyone put together the simple code so that I can understand how it works?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with Drupal's API doc on [Forms](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api.html/6). Also, check out Drupal's documentation on their [Database Abstraction Layer](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/database/6).